# Не срабатывает проверка в цикле

Tags: c, циклы

Имеется задача, в которой вводится строка длиной не более 255 символов, ввод оканчивается по enter. Потом строка выводится в обратном порядке. Обязательные условия - использование языка С, использование только printf и scanf, для определения конца строки использовать strlen.

Вот моя реализация, где не срабатывает проверка, причем я так понимаю что делов инкрементировании index.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    const int SIZE = 255;
    char ar[SIZE];
    printf("Enter a line not more than 255 chars ");
    int index = 0;
    while (ar[index] != 'n' && index < SIZE) {
        scanf("%c", &ar[index]);
        index++;
    }
    int length = 0;
    length = strlen(ar);
    printf("%d", length);
    for (index = length; index >= 0; index--)
        printf("%c", ar[index]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Для начала, Вы читаете в ar[index], **увеличиваете** его и ... проверяете элемент массива, который еще не читали.

Comment: Спасибо,у меня в этом и была загвоздка. Пробовал переписать цикл на for, но было все так же.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А зачем считывать символы в цикле? Функция `scanf` позволяет ограничивать длину считанной строки. Достаточно поместить между символами %  и s число, равное лимиту. К тому же не забывайте при задании длины строки, что последний символ должен быть `\n`

```
const int SIZE = 256;
char ar[SIZE];
scanf ("%255s", ar);
```

Далее либо выводим символы с конца к началу по одному, либо производим реверс всей строки и выводим ее в один прием.

```
int i=strlen(ar)-1, j = 0;
char temp;
while (i>j) {
  temp=ar[i];
  ar[j]=ar[i];
  ar[i]=temp;
  i--;
  j++;
}
printf ("%s\n", ar);
```

Comment: Спасибо, все вышло, дописал по-своему,очень помог совет про scanf. Надо бы справочником функций обзавестись,типа Шилдта

Comment: @RootKit, оказывается Вы man scanf не читали. Тогда подскажу, scanf по формату %s вводит **не стороки**, а "слова". Если надо читать строки смотрите fgets() (или getline).